# How to solve the inverse problem of least-squares?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Focusing on following least squares problem:
  $$\min\limits_{V} \lVert Z - WV \rVert _{_F}^2$$

$$Z∈{R}^{m*n},\quad W∈{R}^{m*k},\quad V∈{R}^{k*n},\quad k\lt m\lt n $$
  This problem can be easily solved given $Z$ and $W$. I assume the solution of this problem as $\overline{V}$.

My question is that,  how can we recover $W$ by $\overline{V}$ and $Z$?

I found something called Inverse Optimization, but cannot figure out the relationship between them.

EDIT: It is acceptable to have a set of $W$ or one feasible $W$ if $W$ is not unique.

($\overline{V}$ and $Z$ are both nonzero matrices, and $Z$ is not promised to be full rank).

Comment: Whatever your W was fixed at in the least squares problem in which you solved for V.  Of course, this combination of V and W won't even be a local minimum, let alone a global minimum, if convergence of the overall algorithm has not yet occurred.  https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better location for this question.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Thank you. You are right. What I concern is an intermediate result before convergence.

Comment: Well, intermediate results may be lousy.  If it hasn't converged to a global minimum,. even the converged result could be lousy.

Comment: [cross-posted](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/29667/how-to-solve-the-inverse-problem-of-least-squares)

Comment: In general the answer is not unique. Let's say $Z=\bar V=0$. Then $W$ can be absolutely anything. You need to assume some non-degeneracy to make it meaningful. So, what are the assumptions you are operating under?

Comment: @fedja Thanks for your comment. Let's assume $Z$ and $\overline{V}$ are non-zero matrices.